# Soundcloud API - Replace Track

Tags: api, soundcloud

I have the API connected and am able to upload tracks, but I haven't found anywhere that references the ability to replace an uploaded track from the API. It's available as a button on the admin of soundcloud.com, but is there any way to do it from the API?

Comment: If you have a pro account, this does seem to be possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812996/soundcloud-api-tracks-info-replace-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to replace the audio for a track, you would need to delete and then re-create it. If you give the track the same title, it should get the same permalink if that's what you're after.

Deleting and recreating a track would involve sending a DELETE request to the /tracks/{track_id} endpoint followed by a POST request to the /me/tracks endpoint with the tracks[asset_data] and tracks[title] parameters at a minimum.

Comment: Bummer! That's what I figured, but since the actual administrative panel allows you to replace I hoped it would be an available thing in the API.

Comment: @Paul Is this the case for artwork images as well as track audio?

Comment: Does this give you a new id#? If so I would imagine that you lose the statistics that belong to the initial recording. Am I correct in this assumption? I also have a bunch of player instances that would need to be updated to the new id. Bummer.

Comment: I implemented DELETE + POST to update tracks at SoundCloud. But my clients asked to leave track's statistics and I implemented simple PUT with new audio-file and it doesn't work. Seems the only way is DELETE+POST with loosing statistics. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435256/soundcloud-api-put-method-not-updating-track-asset-data