# Soundcloud api - tracks info - replace file

Tags: file, replace, soundcloud

A simple question about the soundcloud API, but I can't find this info, and can't make the test by myself since I don't have a pro account:
If a user update (replace) a file, how could I know it? Is the id replaced? Or the date changed? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no real indication for that in the API response, but I guess it could be the case that the `original_content_size` changed.

Comment: ah yes thanks, if I can't have the confirmation that the id changed, I will have to implement that.

Comment: Oh no, it won't work actually. If a wav or aiff track is replaced with a track with the exact same length (which is likely), then I guess that 'original_content_size' won't change. maybe 'created_at'? Marco, are you from Soundcloud, and is it the official answer? Or can I hope for an answer from them? (It's just a little information, but I can't do without...)

Comment: Hey, yes I do work for SoundCloud. created_at only reflects the creation of the track, unfotunately, and I don't think we store when the original files are changed. You're right that if the new file is the same size, then this attribute won't change. Still, even if the new file has length, the size of the file might change. It doesn't always work

Comment: Ah ok sorry. May I ask that you update a song with a pro account, and look what is the ID of this track before and after the update? That would be very very nice :)